# What is the right synonym for the adjective "mean" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

What is the right synonym for the adjective "mean" in this context?

This is the context: The person saying this is talking about a person who is a Vampire.(It's from a video game)

"He's propably got a **mean** complextion problem"

Comment: Be aware that the cited usage is very colloquial / slangy.

Answer (score 3):

In this context the word "mean" means "serious" or "intense".

Another example of the word "mean" in that kind of context would be:
"My grandmother makes a mean casserole".

It is actually considered slang, so you may not find it in a regular dictionary. I was able to find this definition for "mean" [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mean).

You have to scroll down a bit but it says:

MEAN
To describe something as exceptionally good or "cool", normally referring to an item/ non-living thing, but can be used to describe people also.
Ex. 1: My Mama make a mean turkey sandwhich!!
Ex. 2: Damn, that girls got a mean ass!
Ex. 3: Our little league soccer team has mean dribbles.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mean) is a much, much more reputable and reliable resource than Urban Dictionary. Check Definitions 5 c & 5 d. Please consider replacing your UD reference with this one.

Answer (score 1):

The correct meaning of *mean* here is "causing trouble or bother; vexatious; difficult; malicious".

In this case, it is *probably* a shortening of the common idiom "a [real] mean case of [an illness; the blues; the Mondays; etc]."

In the case of a vampire (such as in the game Vampyr) the afflicted persons often have white skin, odd blue veins, and some sort of skin condition: bad complexion.